# WooCommerce Email Notification all customers instantly when I add a New or Update a Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to find a solution to this using plugins but did not work as I wanted, I would like to notify by email all my clients registered when I create or update a product.

My function

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_product_update' );

function my_product_update( $post ) {
    if($post->post_type == "product"){
         $pid=$post->ID;

           // Send Email ?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'role' => 'customer',
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

        $to = $user->user_email;
        // create mail temelate and send mail
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = '', $attachments = array() );
    }
} else {
    // no users found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please user the following action hook of WordPress for custom post type:

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'your_function_name');
 add_action( 'publish_product', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name( $post_id ) {
  // do code here
}
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks. You know the action to send email for all custumers ?

Comment: You have to write custom code to send email to all users. check my another answer.